# Не устанавливается checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть разметка:

```
<div id="bron-1417" class="brons color-status-2" data-brone="1417">
    <div class="width_60proc padding_5px tool-1417">
        <p>Dr. Camscope DCS-103R видеоректоскоп</p>
    </div>
    <div class="width_30proc padding_5px tool-1417 status-2">
        <p>Авторизовано</p>
    </div>
    <div class="width_4proc padding_5px tool-1417 status-2">
        <p><input type="checkbox" id="chech_bron-1417" class="chech_bron"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

При клике по div#bron-1417 прекрасно устанавливается checked в input, но при  клике на сам input не ставится, почему?

```
var id, check;
$('.brons').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    id=$(this).attr('data-brone');
    check=$('#chech_bron-'+id).prop('checked');
    $('#chech_bron-'+id).prop('checked', !check);
});
```

Comment: Попробуй использовать изменение состояния на active, focus. Возможно поможет.

Comment: А какой смысл? Если Без скрипта при клике по input изменяется состояние checked. А с скриптом изменяется только при клики на элемент.

Comment: Предположу, что при клике на сам инпут состояние просто меняется дважды, сначала по штатному поведению, потом по обработчику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт не нужен:

```html
<div id="bron-1417" class="brons color-status-2" data-brone="1417">
  <label>
    <div class="width_60proc padding_5px tool-1417">
     <p>Dr. Camscope DCS-103R видеоректоскоп</p>
    </div>
    <div class="width_30proc padding_5px tool-1417 status-2">
      <p>Авторизовано</p>
    </div>
    <div class="width_4proc padding_5px tool-1417 status-2">
      <p><input type="checkbox" id="chech_bron-1417" class="chech_bron"></p>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

или

```html
<div id="bron-1417" class="brons color-status-2" data-brone="1417">
  <div class="width_60proc padding_5px tool-1417">
    <label for="chech_bron-1417"><p>Dr. Camscope DCS-103R видеоректоскоп</p></label>
  </div>
  <div class="width_30proc padding_5px tool-1417 status-2">
    <label for="chech_bron-1417"><p>Авторизовано</p></label>
  </div>
  <div class="width_4proc padding_5px tool-1417 status-2">
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="chech_bron-1417" class="chech_bron"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не работает потому, что Вы сразу же меняете `checked`, т.к. у Вас стоит событие на родителе (`.brons`). 
Проверяйте `event.target`.

```js
$('.brons').on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id != 'chech_bron-1417') {
    event.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr('data-brone');
    check = $('#chech_bron-' + id).prop('checked');
    $('#chech_bron-' + id).prop('checked', !check);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bron-1417" class="brons color-status-2" data-brone="1417">
  <div class="width_60proc padding_5px tool-1417">
    <p>Dr. Camscope DCS-103R видеоректоскоп</p>
  </div>
  <div class="width_30proc padding_5px tool-1417 status-2">
    <p>Авторизовано</p>
  </div>
  <div class="width_4proc padding_5px tool-1417 status-2">
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="chech_bron-1417" class="chech_bron"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```